# how do I build a dynamic URL in views?

Tags: 7, views

I am using drupal 7, have a content type and two taxonomy categories, size and shape.

Im trying to build a dynamic url such as mysite.com/node/nid/tid/tid, which would get rewrote as e.g mysite.com/page-1/large/square.

I want the content of the url to just show the node, so in this case node/1. But I am also going to make 2 blocks one for category size and another block for category shape which will get the relevant IDs from the url and show the relevant content, in this case block 1 will show large and block 2 will show square.

I thought I could generate the page in views by setting the URL to node/%/%/% or node/%/*/*
and setting arg 1 to nid, but this comes back as page not found.

So I am wondering is this possible in views if not how can I create a url such
/arg1/arg2/arg3 which represents /a nid/a category 1 tid/a category 2 tid, and then populate the page dynamically?

Thanks for any help

edit/

So I have got the arguments working. mysite.com/%/%/% by setting the last argument as the target page rather than the first argument. But how can I rewrite the url. So arg1 becomes node title, arg2 becomes term id 1 and arg3 becomes term id 2 title?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set your pathauto pattern settings to rewrite your URL. Goto **Configurations > Search and metadata > URL aliases > Patterns**. Set the pattern for your content type to:

```
[node:title]/[node:field_...]/[node:field_...]
```

Where the "node:field_..." is replaced with the respective tokens for your taxonomy fields.